# HTMLAgilityPack don't preserves original empty tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

If i have some empty tags like this

```
<td  width="15px"/>
```

Agility pack fixes them to be like

```
<td  width="15px"></td>
```

Is anything possible to do to override this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before saving:

```
if (HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("td"))
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["td"] = HtmlElementFlag.Empty | HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
}
else
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("td", HtmlElementFlag.Empty | HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
}
```

This changes the behavior for all `td` elements which may not be what you want. I don't know of a way to accomplish this per-node.

Comment: There is no way to do this per-node. @MichaelT - empty TD can be problematic to some browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `OptionWriteEmptyNodes` property to true on your `HtmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

While @Corbin March's answer doesn't work as desired, it's the only one I've found that comes close.  The problem is that HAP still does some additional fixup that makes this a problem.

From the original code:

```
<td  width="15px"/>
```

By set the ElementFlags as above the closing element tag indeed is not created, however the original trailing "/" is removed.  This could be a problem depending on  your scenario, it was for me.  The original fragment becomes:

```
<td  width="15px">
```