# Html Agility Pack InnerHtml returns incorrect string with textboxes

Tags: html-agility-pack, innerhtml

The following test code:

```
[Test]
public void PossibleHtmlAgilityPackBug()
{
    const string html = @"<input type=""text"" name=""shouldNotTrim"" />";
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    Assert.That(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, Is.EqualTo(html));
}
```

Results in:

```
Expected string length 42 but was 40. Strings differ at index 39.
Expected: "<input type="text" name="shouldNotTrim" />"
But was:  "<input type="text" name="shouldNotTrim">"
--------------------------------------------------^
```

Is this a bug? Or is there a config that I can change to output that extra "/" I need?

Thanks,

Chi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. INPUT is considered by the parser as an "empty" element (see this for example: [HTMLAgilityPack don't preserves original empty tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389638/htmlagilitypack-dont-preserves-original-empty-tags) on the empty elements subjects), and by default, such elements are rendered without the closing /.

The reasons are historically related to HTML 3.2. Back in those days, INPUT was not required to be closed, although it looks like like a bug today.

This will fix your problem:

```
public void PossibleHtmlAgilityPackBug()
{
    const string html = @"<input type=""text"" name=""shouldNotTrim"" />";
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    Assert.That(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml, Is.EqualTo(html));
}
```

As a side note, the HTML agility pack will not always create an exact equivalent of the html *text*, but it will always try to rebuild something that will be *rendered* the same way. Browsers support an unclosed INPUT without a problem.