# HtmlAgilityPack LoadHtml(string html) lose some tage

Tags: html-agility-pack

I use HtmlAgilityPack  to load a html code, but some tag will be losing.

```
<Item><link>http:...</link><Item>
```

But when I use `LoadHtml(string html)`, the `Outer` and `inner` html I get is

```
<Item><link>http...<Item>
```

The tag `</link>` is lost. Do I need to open some Option?
Thx

Comment: you mean that html looks fine when you inspect it in your browser but not when you load it to a HAP document? if so that is because the html is invalid and your browser fixes the open tags, another thing is the `<link>` is not allowed to have a closing tag

Comment: also note that the `<link>` and its allowed to be inside the `<head>` tag only [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<link>` tag is not supposed to be anywhere, except for the `<head>` section, plus, it's a tag that, according to the definition, is supposed to be self-closed.

You will need to override the settings for "link" tags ([you may need to tweak the settings instead of simply removing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391851/736079)):

```
if (HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("link"))
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("link");
}
```

And depending on the messed-up-ness of your document, you may need to  instruct the HTML Agility pack to stop fixing tags and to support tags in incorrect places.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// You may need to tweak the following options:
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false;
htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax   = false;
```

Comment: `htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = false; htmlDoc.OptionCheckSyntax   = false;` 
That is not useful.|
But 
`if (HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.ContainsKey("link"))
{
    HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("link");
}`
Can solve the problem!